# Searching a string that begins with "Mon" and storing it in element 0 in an array

Tags: php

```
<?php
 $towns = 'Monday Tuesday Sunday Friday';

 $towns1 = strtolower($towns);

$words = explode(" " , $towns1);

echo \n;
echo $words
```

This is what I have so far I have exploded the string into arrays but how do I search or what is the best approach to find words that begins with "Mon" and storing it in a new array ? I'm new to PHP here

Comment: There is only one day in the week that begins with `Mon`. Better search for `Monday` ?

Comment: yes but I just use the days of the week as an example what if I want to find words that end with 'nas' in a string and store it in an array element would it be similar

Comment: So have you tried and reviewed the answers then?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $towns = 'Monday Tuesday Sunday Friday';
    $towns1 = strtolower($towns);
    $input = explode(" ", $towns1);
    //print_r($input);
    $result = preg_grep("/^mon/i", $input);
    print_r($result);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your code:

```
foreach($words as $word){
    switch(true){
        case str_starts_with($word, 'Monday'):
            ## Code to be executed
            break;
        case str_starts_with($word, 'Tuesday'):
            ## Code to be executed
            break;
        case str_starts_with($word, 'Sunday'):
            ## Code to be executed
            break;
        case str_starts_with($word, 'Friday'):
            ## Code to be executed
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Only php 8 and higher because of the [str_starts_with](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-starts-with.php)